# Can extra quotation marks be added to indicate number of speakers?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

I am trying to find out if there is any punctuational representation of three people saying the same thing at the same time. For example, if someone asked "Understand?" and three people simultaneously responded "Got it!"

Obviously, I could make sense of that by adding "all":

> "Got it!" they *all* said.

But I was curious if there was a representation of that without any extra wording. I know someone who asserts that one can use """Got it!""" which doesn't seem right, but I can't seem to find any other type of representation.

Comment: I know of no convention for this. If you make one up and use it, it is likely not  to be understood.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because writing advice questions should be asked at [writers.se].

Comment: What are you writing that you can't afford "all the extra wording" of a three word phrase? Comic books and screenplays both have their own ways to deal with this.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  There is no word or phrase that, of itself, implies that "everyone" spoke said word or phrase simultaneously, and there is no punctuation to indicate this either, so obviously one must add "they said" or some such.  If you want to indicate that they said it in unison, you should write something like "they all said in unison".

Comment: There are a variety of conventions for illustrating this in graphic novel speech bubbles, but there is no such punctuation convention in the English language. You could also say "Got it!", Bob said. "Got it!", Mary said. etc. but that would indicate a sequential rather than simultaneous statement. Your example is the most efficient way to say it. A screenplay might say: "All: Got it!"

Answer (score 1):

> I was curious if there was a representation of that without any extra wording.

### No, there is not.

When used for dialogue, quotation marks indicate a speaker's (verbatim) words--nothing more, nothing less. They don't inform the reader about the number of speakers, only that *someone* is speaking.

In prose, you can use the word *simultaneously* or *all* as you mentioned in your question, or *in unison* (as Hot Licks mentioned in a comment above).

If you are working with speech bubbles in graphics (also mentioned above in Laurel's comment), such as a comic, you can create a bubble with multiple "tails" leading to each of the people speaking.

Check out this [resource](https://litreactor.com/columns/talk-it-out-how-to-punctuate-dialogue-in-your-prose) for further information on using quotation marks for dialogue in prose. The excerpt below provides a basic description for the use of quotation marks and their accompanying dialogue tags:

> Dialogue or direct discourse is usually enclosed in quotation marks, either single like these: ‘____’, or double, like these: “____”. In American English, you are most likely to see the double quotation marks used to indicate a character or person speaking who is not the narrator.
>
> Dialogue usually uses dialogue tags such as “she said,” “he screamed,” “they murmured,” etc. Dialogue tags are a subject and a verb that indicate who is speaking and the method of the speech (spoken/yelled/whispered). In most cases (unless a dialogue tag that indicates thought is used), material inside the quotation marks is considered spoken material.

[Source: "Talk It Out: How to Punctuate Dialogue in Your Prose" by Taylor Houston]

Comment: Also, dialog tags can be dispensed with in alternating dialog after the first pair, if for example, a speaker and audience are engaged in a call and response dialog. Instructions for group speaking in church bulletin or prayer book would use the screen writing convention of listing the speaker first followed by a colin and then the words to be spoken.